# Xml enveloped signature in gSOAP

Tags: xml, digital-signature, sign, gsoap

Does the **gSOAP** support **XML eneveloped signature**? Because It looks like I cannot digitally sign the data before XML is genrated (I have just C++ structures), but as soon as the xml formated data for request are created, I cannot sign them (with CryptXML Functions), because data are already sent.

Answer (score 1):

The gsoap WSSE parsing and verification side *accepts* enveloped signatures. But when sending, creating enveloped signatures is not easily done (gsoap WSSE is a fast streaming WSSE/dsig/xenc encoder). I encourage you to look at gsoap's WSSE [SAML tokens](https://www.genivia.com/doc/wsse/html/wsse.html#wsse_6_4) with enveloped signatures.